# Resizing fonts for current display

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm developing windows 8 application and I have got problem with resizing fonts. For example on big display (with big resolution) fonts are too small to read from distance. Is there a way to resize them - I want to have also option in settings to make fonts bigger/smaller.

Comment: Note on writing question: There is no need for thank you notes (upvote/accept/comment on answers) and [signature](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) as they rarely add context to questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the bottom app bar to increase the front size and you can also make use of the viewbox control which will help you resize the front depending on the resolution of your screen.